# SEO for URL where widget resides - not where content is hosted - iFrame vs DIV

Tags: seo, iframe, widgets

I do not care about SEO for the source URL of content, but would like my customers' websites to benefit from the content being served.

Does it make a difference whether the content is served in iFrame of DIV?

How do I optimize things?

Comment: Is the content the same on all of the websites? Is it powered by JavaScript? Is the content in the DIV ultimately an iframe?

Comment: If content is being served from an iframe, Google wont count the content as appearing on the page the iframe is displaying in, it will see the content as being on the actual iframe URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use a div if you want your widget to get indexed on other people's sites. Google doesn't index iframes and they aren't likely to start anytime soon.